# NestJS and React - How to send back a HTTP error response

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, nestjs, redux-thunk

I am building an app with React and NestJS.

In NestJS, I have an API endpoint to upload a photo like so:

```
@Controller('api/upload')
export class UploadController {
    constructor(private readonly uploadService: UploadService) {}

    @Post()
    @UseInterceptors(
        FileInterceptor('image', {
            storage: diskStorage({
                destination: './myphoto',
                filename: (req, file, cb) => {
                    if (file.mimetype !== 'image/png')
                        // how do I return an Http error message here?

                    return cb(null, 'myphoto.png');
                },
            }),
        }),
    )
    uploadPhoto(@UploadedFile() image) {
    }
}
```

In React, I am using axios and redux-thunk to hit this endpoint like so:

```
export const uploadPhotoAsync = (data: FormData) => {
    return (dispatch: ThunkDispatch<{}, {}, AnyAction>) => {
        return axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/upload', data)
            .then(() => {
                dispatch({ type: UPLOAD_PHOTO_COMPLETE, error: null });
            })
            .catch((e) => {
                dispatch({ type: UPLOAD_PHOTO_COMPLETE, error: e.message });
            });
    };
};
```

As you can see, if there is an error message, we want to catch it and store it in state to display to the user.

My question is: how do I use NestJS to return an error message so that it can be caught by my front-end error handler? In the `if` statement in my controller, I tried just doing something like `throw new UnsupportedMediaException("My error message here")` but all that appears to do is throw the error on the server-side and nothing gets sent to the client.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I didn't try this, but isn't the image param passed to `uploadPhoto` of the same type as where you do your test? So then inside your controller you can do the `image.mimetype` test. Otherwise - looking at the code - the file is available in `request.file`.